# Include wwwroot from a library project?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm working on a project structure with multiple projects serving the same set of static files.

At start each project will server both the static files and the API services but later on I plan to separate some of them into multiple projects.

- ProjectA will server both static files and API
- ProjectB1 will only serve the same static files as in ProjectA
- ProjectB2 will only serve the API

In a classic VS library you can have files marked as content. These will be included in the build output of any project that references that library.

I tried to make a project ProjectStatic containing the static files and reference it from both ProjectA and ProjectB1 but none of the files in ProjectStatic are included in the output of ProjectA nor ProjectB1.

Can this be done using project.json?

Comment: currently is is not possible to include content files in the nuget that is created by building, but my understanding is that it should be possible once we get to RC2

Comment: As it stands, I've written a few gulp tasks to copy shared HTML/JS/CSS assets from a library project to a couple of different web projects within a solution - it works quite well if a bit hacky... If that sounds helpful, I can write it up as an answer with details of how I did it? It runs as a pre-build task each time, so no manual syncing needed.

Comment: @MarkHughes I've already a plan in case that would be the only solution, but feel free to share your. It won't help in my particular situation but others might find it useful.

Comment: I like the look of @Tseng 's answer - if that works that would be a much more straightforward answer to the question than my gulp hack.

Comment: It may not completely solve his issue though, as the resources will be compiled into the assembly. But if your projects share the same server and same virtual file system (i.e. run in **same** docker container) you can also just symlink the folders. Alternatively you can implement your own `IFileProvider` that will reads the files from a common folder you choose

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `UseStaticFiles` call with a `EmbeddedFileProvider`. It's part of the rc1-final package, as you can see [here](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=EmbeddedFileProvider).

Just for future readers:

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
        FileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(
            assembly: Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("OpenIddict.Assets")),
            baseNamespace: "OpenIddict.Assets")
});
```

`OpenIddict.Assets` is the assembly/project name that contains the static resources.

**Update:**

After digging a bit through the source and finding the right repository, there is also a `PhysicalFileProvider` you may be able to use instead of packing it into the assembly and point to an arbitrary folder on the file system.

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("/path/to/shared/staticfiles")
});
```

**Update 2:**

Just for the sake of completeness, there is also a `CompositeFileProvider` which you could use to have multiple `IFileProviders` to create some kind of virtual file system structure, i.e. if the file is not found in the `PhysicalFileProvider` given location, load it from an `EmbeddedFileProvider`.

Comment: I think the EmbeddedFileProvider comes closest to the original question, not sure how PhysicalFileProvider will help getting files from a linked project.