# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Serve static files from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am attempting to serve an API and Angular Front-End with an ASP.NET Core 2.1 backend. `Startup.cs` is in the project `MyApp.Api`. I want my static files to be pulled from the wwwroot of another project, `MyApp.FrontEnd`.

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198633/include-wwwroot-from-a-library-project) which describes the following method

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
    FileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(
        assembly: Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("OpenIddict.Assets")),
        baseNamespace: "OpenIddict.Assets")
});
```

However, when I try to replace "OpenIddicts.Assets" with my project name, I get the following error:

> FTL Application startup exception
>       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
>       'MyApp.FrontEnd, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>       The system cannot find the file specified.
>       File name: 'MyApp.FrontEnd, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

The GitHub repository referenced in the post linked above seems to no longer exist. I assume I'm missing  somewhere fairly obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a reference to `MyApp.FrontEnd` from `MyApp.Api`?

Comment: Any reason you can't use `PhysicalFileProvider` or do the files need to come from an assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyApp.FrontEnd.dll` must exist in output folder. If You publish main project (which has reference to `MyApp.FrontEnd`) then everything should work.

If you have access to some types from assembly then you can try `Assembly.GetAssembly(type)` instead of `Assembly.Load(...)`, i.e.

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
    FileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(
        assembly: Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SomeClassFromAssembly)),
        baseNamespace: "OpenIddict.Assets")
});
```